# "undefined method 'zero' for Nil:Class" when #sum the Array without Nils

Tags: compile-time, weak-typing, crystal-lang

The issue happens when the variable, that the array was built from, was a `nil` initially.

```
y = (1..2).map do
  v = nil
  v = 1
  v
end
p y       # => [1, 1]
p y.class # => Array(Int32)
p y.sum   # => 2
```

When `v` stops being `nil` on a condition, that is potentially computational and not solvable while compiling:

```
z = (1..2).map do
  v = nil
  v = 1 if true
  v
end
p z       # [1, 1]
p z.class # => Array(Nil | Int32)
```

The array gets more complex type, that isn't compatible with current `sum` implementation, so `p z.sum` causes compile time error:

```
undefined method 'zero' for Nil:Class (compile-time type is (Nil | Int32):Class)
 def sum(initial = T.zero)
                     ^~~~
```

How am I supposed to fight this properly?
Or maybe it waits for some better implementation of stdlib `sum` method or anything else?

UPD: `inject` gives the same:

```
p z.inject{ |i, j| i + j }

undefined method '+' for Nil (compile-time type is (Nil | Int32))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Iterator#compact_map` to select non-nil values. The compiler will be able to infer a `Array(Int32)` in that case.

http://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/e85

```
z = (1..2).map do
  v = nil
  v = 1 if true
  v
end

pp typeof(z) # => Array(Nil | Int32)
pp z # => z = [1, 1]

y = z.compact_map(&.itself)
pp typeof(y) # => Array(Int32)
pp y # => y = [1, 1]
```

Also, notice that `typeof(Expr)` and `Expr.class` might lead to different results. The first is the compile time type and the later is the runtime type.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution to what Brian says is to use `sum` with a block:

http://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/ein

```
z = (1..2).map do
  v = nil
  v = 1 if true
  v
end
puts z.sum { |x| x || 0 } #=> 2
```